# C# - Call a derived base method in the derived context

Tags: c#, generic-derivation

Tried to search the web but found nothing so far so here my question:

I want to index model-information via attributes on the different members.
To do this i created a function in a base class that gathers all needed information when called.
This method is derived into the different models so that they can all be indexed.

```
Base()
{
    public virtual void Index() {...}
}
```

In the base class I'm calling a generic method that gives me acces to the indexing server for the specific model that I want to save there

```
using (var indexFacade = IndexFacadeFactory.GetIndexFacade(configuration, this))
{
    indexFacade.Execute(this, operation);
}
```

The issue I'm currently having is that when calling the factory it retrieves the information for the base-class.

What I want to acomplish is something like this:

```
Derived : Base
{
   [IndexingKey]
   long Id { get; set; }

   [IndexingField]
   string SomeValue { get; set; }
}

var derived = new Derived();
derived.Index();
```

My indexFacade holds the type of

```
IndexFacadeBase<Base>
```

I'm aware of the polimorphism here and why this happens.

My question is:
How can i call

```
derived.Index();
```

so that the context from which it is called is not from the base-class without overwriting it?

Further information:

The method that is called looks like this:

```
public static IndexFacadeBase<T> GetIndexFacade<T>(IndexInfo.IndexConfiguration config, T model)
        {
            IndexFacadeBase<T> retVal;
            .....
            return retVal;
        }
```

The **T** has the type of **Base**.

The **model** has the type of **Derived**.

Maybe that clears up some of the Problems.

I get back:

```
  IndexFacadeBase<Base>
```

I would need back:

```
   IndexFacadeBase<Derived>
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "derived context"?

Comment: @MatthewWatson exactly. What kind of information you want to pass? You can always do this.GetType() and retrieve an actual derived type.

Comment: I have the IndexFacadeBase<Base> when i call derived.Index()

I would need IndexFacadeBase<Derived>.
The type comes from a generic and since it's called from the base the context results in IndexFacadeBase<Base>

Answer (score 2):

I may not be fully understanding your question, but aren't you simply looking to override the method in the derived class?

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Index() { }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Index() { } // here is the override.
    long Id { get; set; }
    string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you do this:

```
var derived = new Derived();
derived.Index();
```

The derived class' `Index` method is called.

Comment: It would work that way, yes.

The Problem just would be that i would have to copy/paste the whole block into the different models. they way it currently is would do everything without the need to copy it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would work if your `IndexFacadeBase<Base>` was changed to `IndexFacadeBase<T> where T:Base`.

Comment: IndexFacadeBase<Base> is the type resulting from the call

'
public static IndexFacadeBase<T> GetIndexFacade<T>(IndexInfo.IndexConfiguration config, T model)
{
            IndexFacadeBase<T> retVal;
}
'

this is the method in short that is called.

T is of type Base
model is of type Derived

Comment: I'm sorry the formatting in the answer is ugly i will post a regular answer to get the formatting right...